# Buscar items de um array de objetos dentro do JSON

Tags: javascript

Preciso pegar os itens que estão dentro do array de itens de um JSON local e imprimi-los numa tabela do meu HTML. Os objetos que estão fora do array eu consegui pegar facilmente, mas não estou conseguindo acessar o array e pegar os objetos de lá de dentro.

```
{
    "xmlItem": [
        {
            "cProd": "000000000000105656",
            "nitem": "1",
            "cest": "2005000",
            "cstCson": "520",
            "pIcms": "18.0000",
            "pRedBC": "41.1700",
            "pRedBCST": "0.0000",
            "cstPis": "01",
            "cstCofins": "01",
            "cstIpi": null,
            "unidade": "UN",
            "preco": "4.1130555556",
            "quantidade": "36.0000",
            "total": "148.07",
            "cEAN": "7500435127233",
            "xprod": "ABS HIG ALWAYS BASICO SC C/ABA 16UN L+P-",
            "ncm": "96190000",
            "cfop": "5102"
        },
        {
            "cProd": "000000000000105661",
            "nitem": "2",
            "cest": "2005000",
            "cstCson": "520",
            "pIcms": "18.0000",
            "pRedBC": "41.1700",
            "pRedBCST": "0.0000",
            "cstPis": "01",
            "cstCofins": "01",
            "cstIpi": null,
            "unidade": "UN",
            "preco": "2.1992592593",
            "quantidade": "54.0000",
            "total": "118.76",
            "cEAN": "7500435127226",
            "xprod": "ABS HIG ALWAYS BASICO SC C/ABA 8UN",
            "ncm": "96190000",
            "cfop": "5102"
        }
    ],
    "cnpj": "05997742001390",
    "xnome": "UNIMARKA DISTRIBUIDORA S/A",
    "xfant": "UNIMARKA - UNISUL FEIRA SANTAN",
    "nnf": "791762",
    "chNFe": "29220205997742001390550000007917621008387055"
}
```

Código que fiz para pegar os objetos de fora do array:

```
    const c = (elem) => {
        return document.getElementById(elem);
    }

    c('load').innerHTML = 'Dados do fornecedor:'
    c('btn2').style.display = 'inline-block';
    c('btn').style.display = 'none';

    let xml = fetch('nf.json')
        .then(function (response){
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (json){
            c('chave').innerHTML = 'Chave de acesso:'+ ' ' + json.chNFe;
            c('cnpj').innerHTML = 'CNPJ:'+ ' ' +json.cnpj;
            c('nnf').innerHTML = 'Número NF:'+ ' ' +json.nnf;
            c('fantasia').innerHTML = 'Nome fantasia:'+ ' ' +json.xfant;
            
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))    
}
```

Comment: Fiz uma edição no tópico.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao site. É importante **[edit], remover o código complexo e no lugar adicionar um [mcve] (NÃO delete e NÃO repita a pergunta)**, com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva e então aguarde o processo de reabertura (que será avaliado por outros usuários). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uma maneira simples de resolver o problema é criar uma função auxiliar para iterar o array em questão, supondo que possui o objeto com o formato que está na pergunta basta fazer o seguinte:

```
const imprimir = (arrr) => {
for (let i = 0; i < arrr.length; i++) {
    chaves = Object.keys(arrr[i])
    for (let j = 0; j < chaves.length; j++) {
        console.log(`${chaves[j]}: ${arrr[i][chaves[j]]}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Para esta implementação eu utilizei o método [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

O método `Object.keys()` retorna um array de propriedades enumeráveis de um determinado objeto, na mesma ordem em que é fornecida por um laço `for...in` (a diferença é que um laço for..in  enumera propriedades que estejam na cadeia de protótipos).

---

Depois basta chamar esta função passando o array como parâmetro da seguinte forma:

```
const a = { //o seu json };
imprimir(a.xmlItem)
```

Depois basta aplicar a sua lógica para preencher o html.